# How to retrive value using viper with golang from intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, viper-go, goland

I wanna retrive variant a from intellij ,but failed.

```
func main(){ 
    a:=viper.GetString("a") 
    fmt.println(a)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `-a=2`, just as you would add any normal parameter to the command line

Comment: I have tried that program arguments: -a=2 , but it failed.

Comment: Then you need to post more code because the question is incomplete. Based on the information I have I cannot replicate it.

Comment: It is complete, the source code use viper to getstring, but failed. But how the intellij config the params?

Answer (score 0):

Have an empty config.yml file in project

```
viper.SetConfigName("config")
viper.SetConfigType("yml")
viper.AddConfigPath("")
viper.AutomaticEnv()

err := viper.ReadInConfig()
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err)
    panic("error initializing viper config")
}

value := viper.GetInt("a")
fmt.Println(value)
```